# Creating NSScrollView with NSTableView without a nib—missing constraints on the TableView

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa, nsscrollview, snapkit

I'm trying to build an NSScrollView with a NSTableView as the content, but I'm getting an error saying I'm missing constaints on the Table and I'm not sure what it is I'm missing. I'm using SnapKit for the layout, and the error message is `Detected missing constraints for <NSTableView: 0x10100aaf0>.  It cannot be placed because there are not enough constraints to fully define the size and origin.`.

My code for the ViewController is:

```
class MainViewController: NSViewController {

  let table: NSTableView = {
    let t = NSTableView(frame: .zero)
    t.headerView?.isHidden = false
    t.selectionHighlightStyle = .regular
    t.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    t.autoresizingMask = [.height, .width]
    t.usesAlternatingRowBackgroundColors = true
    let col1 = NSTableColumn(identifier: NSUserInterfaceItemIdentifier("Name"))
    col1.headerCell = NSTableHeaderCell(textCell: "Name")
    t.addTableColumn(col1)
    return t
  }()

  required init() {
    super.init(nibName: nil, bundle: nil)
  }

  required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
    fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
  }

  override func loadView() {
    view = NSView(frame: .zero)

    let scrollView = NSScrollView(frame: .zero)
    scrollView.hasVerticalScroller = true
    scrollView.autohidesScrollers = false
    scrollView.documentView = table

    view.addSubview(scrollView)

    /// Layout
    scrollView.snp.makeConstraints { make in
      make.edges.equalToSuperview().inset(Padding.large)
    }
  }
```

Most of the online guides are geared towards using a Nib but I'm trying to do it programmatically. Anyone know how it's done? I;m using XCode 9.2 and Swift 4. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I silenced the errors by simply letting the table view use the constraints automatically set by the auto resizing mask. SnapKit automatically sets the line `translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false`, so setting this to `true` seems to work.

```
let table: NSTableView = {
  let t = NSTableView(frame: .zero)
  t.headerView?.isHidden = false
  t.selectionHighlightStyle = .regular
  t.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = true
  t.usesAlternatingRowBackgroundColors = true
  let col1 = NSTableColumn(identifier: NSUserInterfaceItemIdentifier("Name"))
  col1.headerCell = NSTableHeaderCell(textCell: "Name")
  t.addTableColumn(col1)
  return t
}()
```

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that you forgot to add constraints for the `tableView` itself, to describe how it should be laid out in the enclosing scroll view.

You can set a **symbolic breakpoint** on `DETECTED_MISSING_CONSTRAINTS`. [Here is a video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pz3k4mAdd8I) that shows how symbolic breakpoints can be set, in case if you have never come across them.

It should give more insight into what exactly is wrong. Constraints are a tricky business and may be difficult to reason about without seeing the complete picture.

Comment: Thanks for that. I wondered how to set a symbolic breakpoint. However I'm still stuck on what to add the `tableView` constraints to. I've tried snapping the edges to the `scrollView.content.edges` but it doesn't work out... the scroll view goes to a zero size and I'm unable to resize it in the window. The code I tried is: `table.snp.makeConstraints { make in
      make.edges.equalTo(scrollView.contentView.snp.edges)
    }`